# How do I convert a hash's values into lambdas recursively?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have a Hash that looks like this:

```
     {
       :a => "700",
       :b => "600",
       :c => "500",
       :d => "400",
       :e => "300",
       :f => {
         :g => "200",
         :h => [
           "test"
         ]
       }
    }
```

my goal is to iterate over this hash and return a copy that have all the values wrapped in a lambda, similar to this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/dca87ec5d8038b2d436a75ad6119c8eb67b73e70/spec/paperclip/style_spec.rb#L44

I went with `each_with_object({})` but best I can do is to wrap only the first level, so I tried to check when I meet another Hash in the cycle (`:f` in this case, only it's key's values should be a lambda unless they are a hash as well) and treat it, but it's becoming quite troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def hash_values_to_lambda(old_hash)
  {}.tap do |new_hash|
    old_hash.each do |key, value|
      new_hash[key] =
        if value.is_a?(Hash)
          hash_values_to_lambda(value)
        else
          lambda { value } # or -> { value } with new syntax
        end
    end
  end
end
```

If you want, you can go with `each_with_object` instead of `tap`:

```
old_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), new_hash|
  # everything else remains the same
end
```